# TinyMCE in PHP with sub.domain.com

Tags: php, tinymce, subdomain

I have this config file http://pastebin.org/85981

The problem is before I have change

```
$mcImageManagerConfig['filesystem.rootpath']
```

from simplecms.info to cms.schemecloud.com it has no problems.  But after I change the domain it is giving me a problem when I select the URL.  It is only coming with .com and not cms.schemecloud.com.

I can't find out of why this problem happen.

I use [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) and [images manager plugin](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/plugins_imagemanager.php)

Comment: might be best asked at http://serverfault.com

Comment: Your config is empty. Please add it to the question or remove the question as it can not be answered and is of no use any longer.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to comment, so I will put my questions here in an Answer..

The path you have provided looks pretty nasty with the ../../../../../ in there. Maybe try providing the absolute path?

Also, even though thats a sub domain, I'm assuming that the **cms.schemecloud.com** is a folder, which means that it should have no problem with that as its not attempting to do some server forward or something.

You should also verify the value of **$_SESSION['USER']['DOMAIN']** to make sure its valid. I would try to print out **$mcImageManagerConfig['filesystem.rootpath']** just to make sure its producing the path you are expecting.

So I would try to use an absolute path, that way you know for sure that the path is correct, and that you just aren't missing an ../ somewhere, or have one too many.

Good luck!